# How do i connect values to my listview in android and fetch them according to item click

Tags: android

Actually I am making an emergency number app and I want phone numbers to be clicked according to list view item clicked.

So I want different phone numbers behind the list item click and make them to be in use there may be 2 or 3 phone number and each will be behind a button.

For example, like these steps:

1. either you call from city "lahore", "karachi"
2. and eg if karachi
   button clicked, it will fetch data(phone no) according to "karachi"
   city and do call.

.

```
public class EmergencyContacts extends ListActivity {

  static final String[] EmergencyNumbers = new String[]{
        "Ambulance","Hilal-e-Ahmar","Edhi Trust","Bomb Disposal","Board of Secondary Education",
        "Chambers of Commerce & Industry","Civil Defence","Civil Secretariat","Export Promotion ",
        "Bureau","Fatmid Blood ","Transfusion ","Fire Brigade Center","General post office(GPO)",
        "Govt. transport(GTS)","Hospital Civil(casualties)","Hospital services (Casualties)",
        "Income Tax","Metropolitan corp.","News Agency(APP)","Police Emergency","Railway Station (City)",
        "PIA Flight Enquiry","PIA Reservation","PIA Cargo","Passport Office","PTV ","Pakistan Tourism Dev. Corp.",
        "PAF (Recrut)","Pakistan Army (Recruiting)","Pakistan Navy (Recruiting)","Radio Pakistan","Railway Enquiry",
        "Railway Reservation (Cantt.)","Railway Reservation (city)","Sui Gas Complaints","Time Enquiry",
        "Telephone Enquiry","Telephone Complaints","Trunk Overseas ","Booking","Trunk inland Enquiry","Phonogram",
        "Overseas Booking","Overseas Enquiry","Telegraph Enquiry","Text Book Board","University","University Allama Iqbal",
        "University of Engin and Tech","Weather (Enq)","Wapda (Enq)","PAKISTAN TOURISM DEV. CORP","PAKISTAN ARMY (RECRUITING)",
         "PAKISTAN NAVY (RECRUITING)"


   };



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,EmergencyNumbers));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  }

  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,int position,long id){

    //TODO Auto generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Call to?"+"\n"+getListView().getItemAtPosition(position))
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                   // EmergencyContacts.this.finish();


                     Intent callTo = new Intent(EmergencyContacts.this,CallTo.class);
                    startActivity(callTo);

                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: is your problem to reconize which item was clicked? If yes, use tag for the listview items

Comment: how to use tag can you give me some link please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think you should use HashMap for that purpose also you can use ArrayMap for that
or also you can use ArrayList
or Make a getter setter of Imargency Number like following

```
    class EmergencyNumber {

    private String number;
    private String type;


    public setType(String type){

        this.type = type

    }

    public setNumber(String number){

        this.number = number

    }



    public getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public getNumber(){
        return number;
    }

}
```

and use it like ArrayList

for ex i am taking EmergencyNumber Object method
set your info in ArrayList like follows

```
    ArrayList<EmergencyNumber> nT = new ArrayList<EmergencyNumber>();

EmergencyNumber emergencyObject = EmergencyNumber();
emergencyObject.setNumber("888");
emergencyObject.setType("Ambulance");
nT.add(emergencyObject);

EmergencyNumber emergencyObject = EmergencyNumber();
emergencyObject.setNumber("8882");
emergencyObject.setType("Doctor");
nT.add(emergencyObject);
```

set this Arraylist in your adapter

```
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v,int position,long id){

    EmergencyNumber nTSingle =  nT.get(position);
    nTSingle.getNumber();

}
```

by this method you can also put comparable so you can put shorting in your listview

Comment: how do i set values for my list

Answer (score 4):

Method `onListItemClick` has position parameter which indicate current click item position in `EmergencyNumbers`.

So you can access to array item with

```
EmergencyNumbers[position]
```

Comment: dear how do i set values for my list

Comment: if you want to make link between names and phone numbers, better use hashmap or create Class which holds both name and numbers. @M.Adil

Answer (score 0):

```
//TODO Auto generated method stub
super.onListItemClick(l,v,position,id);




AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Call to?"+"\n"+EmergencyNumbers[position])
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               // EmergencyContacts.this.finish();


                 Intent callTo = new Intent(EmergencyContacts.this,CallTo.class);
                startActivity(callTo);

            }
        });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();
```